# Can all equations with one unknown x be re-arranged to x = ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Apologies for being rusty..

I was recently looking at the calculation of yield to maturity for bonds and was wondering why people in the industry resort to a trial error approach when calculating them.

The YTM calculations boil down to equations like these, where `i` is the YTM
(Source: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/y/yieldtomaturity.asp):

[image]

So my specific question is

> 1) Can the above equation be re-arranged to a form `i = ...` where I can calculate the right side numerically?

and my general question would be

> 2) Can't all equations with a single unknown be transformed into `i = ...` ?

Comment: Consider the equation $42=x\cdot e^x$ with $x$ as the unknown variable. You cannot solve this equation by using only elementay functions.

Comment: This equation, moreover, probably amounts to a quintic polynomial in $i$, which has been proven not to be solvable (in general).

Answer (score 0):

You can note that $(1+i)$ is to the power 5. In the complex world, there are 5 solutions to the equation $(1+x)^5 = a$. If you are dealing with positive reals (assuming i is a positive reals), there is only one solution (sometimes none). So we will assume that $i$ is a positive or zero real.

1) is no in the complex world.
However there are techniques to solve it using computers.

2) is no.